# All-Day Events in iOS 9 Today

Tags: calendar, notifications

When I pull down the Notification Center, the "Today" view seems to exclude *all-day* events.

For example, I have 2 events for today:

1. "Lunch", scheduled at noon
2. "Ask A Stupid Question Day", an all-day event

My iOS9 Today view says

> Wednesday, September 30th
>
> The first thing on your calendar today is "Lunch", in 46 minutes.

If I delete "Lunch" from my calendar, the Today view simply says

> Wednesday, September 30th

Why doesn't an all-day event get the same respect as a normal event? Can I change this (stupid) behavior? Am I missing something?

Note: I'm not talking about the Notification Center's Calendar widget (although, it too doesn't not display my all-day event. I guess at least my all-day event is being *consistently* ignored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All-day events don't show in Notification Center.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for verifying. My feedback is: "that sucks." I'll let apple know at the link you provided - thanks!